# How do you create cogs and what is the error here?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

***my main.py***

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from secret import TOKEN


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents, case_insensitive=True, owner_id=262215934322671616)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')
    print("At Your Service, Sir")
    print("------------------")
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f'Hi, my name is {client.user.name}. Currently in development, but come back later!'))


for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs. {filename[:-3]}')
        print(f'Loaded {filename[:-3]}')

        
client.run(TOKEN)
```

***my corg (greetings.py)***

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Greetings(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    @commands.command()
    async def hi(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'seems that i can @ people now, so hey {ctx.author.mention}!')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Greetings(client))
```

i've tried a different approach in main.py:

```
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        initial_extensions.append("cogs." + filename[:-3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        client.load_extension(extension)
```

and ended up with error

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  client.load_extension(extension)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

and still nothing. it doesn't show any error and loads the corg which can be seen through `print(f'Loaded {filename[:-3]}')`
i have no experience with cogs and if someone can point me in the right direction i'd really appreciate this!

Answer (score 1):

> coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited

The error is telling you what the problem is (as errors usually do). `load_extension` is a coroutine and you're not awaiting it. Similarly, `add_cog` is also a coroutine that you're not awaiting, and your `setup` is not a coroutine while it should be.

The migration guide explains how to adapt to this: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

Your code looks like you got it from an outdated tutorial somewhere. This is one of the main reasons (along with many others) why you shouldn't use tutorials and instead just read the docs.

Also, don't change presence in `on_ready`. If you make API calls in `on_ready` Discord has a high chance to disconnect you. There's literally 0 reason to change presence here, you can just pass the `status` and `activity` when you initialize your `Client` instance...